# Extract Input field filled data from Electron BrowserView

Tags: javascript, npm, electron, chromium

For example, here is a simple `BrowserWindow` with appropriate security settings except for `webviewTag: true` which is necessary for this project.

```
let webPrefs = {
    plugins: false,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
    webviewTag: true,
    sandbox: true,
    enableRemoteModule: false,
    contextIsolation: true,
    disableBlinkFeatures: "Auxclick",
    webSecurity: true
};

let winOpts = {
    ...
    show: true,
    webPreferences: webPrefs
};

...

win = new BrowserWindow(winOpts);
const view = new BrowserView(winOpts);
win.setBrowserView(view);

...

view.webContents.loadURL("https://example.com").then(result => {
....
});
```

Suppose that the `example.com` website contains `<form>` with several `<input>` fields.

Users will type text on these `<input>` fields.

I want to extract the 'manually filled' text from those `<input>` fields.
The webpage is not mine and thus cannot modify the website.

`webContents.executeJavaScript()` can be a start point, but couldn't find how to 'extract' the value itself to the `main` process.

(filling the forms from main process can be done by using the function above.)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main import `ipcMain` from `electron` like this

```
const { ipcMain, app, BrowserWindow,BrowserView } = require("electron");
```

in your `webPrefs` add preload file. for example

```
let webPrefs = {
    plugins: false,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    nodeIntegrationInWorker: false,
    webviewTag: true,
    sandbox: true,
    enableRemoteModule: false,
    contextIsolation: true,
    disableBlinkFeatures: "Auxclick",
    webSecurity: true,
    preload:"./preload.js"
};
```

create a new preload file and named it "preload.js". of course you can name it and to anything you want just make sure you set the correct filename in the `preload` above.

this file is like a bridge between you webview and main process. A preload script runs before the renderer process is loaded, and has access to both renderer globals (e.g. window and document) and a Node.js environment.

put the following code in `preload.js` file

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

window.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  //dom_element_id = the id of input element you want
  if (e.target.id === "dom_element_id")
    ipcRenderer.invoke("INPUT_OCCURED", e.target.value);
});
```

now go back to your main file and and for example you can add

```
  win.loadURL("https://www.example.com");

  ipcMain.handle("INPUT_OCCURED", (event, data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

that all the code you need. now with some more explanation.
the preload file is loaded before the webview content and can run anything you want. its also had access to node stuff. what we do it communicate between the preload and the main using ipc. we adding a global listener in the preload which listing to all input event. then he checks and if the id is match the `dom_element_id` its send the dom element value to main. the main got the event data in `INPUT_OCCURED` he listing on

the reason i add a global listener instead of get the element and add listener to him is just for simplicity of the example

Comment: Thanks! I forgot using `preload` script at first time. Just slightly modified to add listener to specific `<input>` element like `document.getElementById('myinput').addEventListener('change', (e) => {});` and put this on `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` to ensure catching the `<input>`.